# Плагины для sublime text 3

Tags: c++, sublime-text

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста полезные плагины для удобного написания кода на С++ в sublime text 3

Comment: Для начала сформулируйте что именно для вас значит "удобное написание кода". До того можете вопользоваться советами из гугла: [раз](https://izevg.ru/blog/2015-04/gotovim-sublime-text-3-dlya-razrabotki-c-cplusplus-koda), [два](http://www.freshtechtips.com/2015/03/sublime-text-c-cplusplus-add-ons-packages.html), и т.д.

Comment: если вы пишет под *nix то там из коробки есть компилятор gcc и g++ нужно толкьо gdb https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeGDB и собственно все. sublime это не IDE а текстовый редактор с раширенными фун-ми